# How to add material UI component in the Columns of jspreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, spreadsheet

Hello Everyone I am using https://jspreadsheet.com/ to create tables , I need to add material UI component in place of default columns , Is there any way I can do this ?

I am using 8.6.8 version

Answer (score 0):

This example helps you to add a material icon to a column.

```html
    <html>
    <script src="https://jspreadsheet.com/v8/jspreadsheet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jsuites.net/v4/jsuites.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jspreadsheet.com/v8/jspreadsheet.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v4/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto|Material+Icons" />
    <div id="spreadsheet"></div>
     
    <script>
    var action = function() {
        var methods = {};
     
        methods.createCell = function(cell, value, x, y, instance, options) {
            var input = document.createElement('i');
            input.className = 'material-icons';
            input.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            input.style.fontSize = '22px';
            input.innerHTML = "search";
            input.onclick = function() {
                var id = instance.getRowId(y);
                // Do some action
                alert(id);
            }
     
            cell.appendChild(input);
     
            // Readonly
            cell.classList.add('readonly');
        }
     
        return methods;
    }();
     
    jspreadsheet(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {
        worksheets: [{
            minDimensions: [4,4],
            columns: [
                { type: action, width:'100px' },
            ],
        }],
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

A running example:
https://jspreadsheet.com/v8/docs/persistence